# Replaying Arcanum, what to install and in what order and why?

Tags: mods, arcanum-of-steamworks-and-magick

Are there mods or any types of improvements for Arcanum: Of Steamworks and Magick Obscura?

Where can I find them, and which ones are essential?

I'm hoping to play it on a widescreen and I'm hoping to play a relatively bug-free game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice step-by-step guide was posted on reddit a few months ago, I'd suggest following that: [[Step-by-step modding guide] Arcanum: Of Steamworks and Magick Obscura](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/chxyd/stepbystep_modding_guide_arcanum_of_steamworks/) (by billyblaze).

Comment: My reddit privileges were revoked at work (with due cause) so I'll have to look at this after work.